# onBackPressed() not called / Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am testing a tiny Android App where I need to perform some action when a back button is pressed. I have prepared the following function in Kotlin:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    println("onBackPressed CALLED")
}
```

I must be missing some detail, because the function is never called.
I expect it to be called when the back button is pressed.

Any comment from a second eye may be helpful.

In case this may be useful, hereafter is the relevant code for the activity:

```
package me.soft.myapp

import ........

class ModifyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    private var constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout? = null
    .....

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify)

        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.main)
        ......
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        println("onStop CALLED")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        println("onResume CALLED")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        println("onDestroy CALLED")
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        println("onRestart CALLED")
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        println("onBackPressed CALLED")
    }
}
```

**--***********************************************--**

In order to reproduce my issue I made a tiny project. It has two activities. And I checked that it still has the same problem.

Here is the *MainActivity.kt* file:

```
package me.soft.trybackbtnaction

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }


    fun fireSubActivity(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, SubActivity::class.java).apply {}
        startActivity(intent)
    } /* End of fireSubActivity */
}
```

Here is the *SubActivity.kt* file:

```
package me.soft.trybackbtnaction

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class SubActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub)
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        println("onBackPressed CALLED")
    }
}
```

And this is the *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="mib.software.trybackbtnaction">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TryBackBtnAction"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".SubActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: for me its working in my device above your code, can you please add more code for your activity

Comment: Have your checked your logcat window if it printing `onBackPressed CALLED`?

Comment: Not it is not printing "onBackPressed CALLED", this is why I am saying the function is never called.

Comment: Strange see this [**logcat screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3JTF.png)

Comment: I see and I believe you. In my case it is not called, I don't know why.

Comment: Please share your whole activity code

Comment: @AskNilesh. I have updated the post, please take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246632/discussion-between-asknilesh-and-michel).

Comment: what if you remove  or comment out this line:
super.onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

Try writing like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    println("onBackPressed CALLED")
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too before, but it made no difference.

Comment: I added information to the post,please have a look. It should make it easy to reproduce the bug and hopefully make it clear where I am missing something.

Comment: have called this method manually? or you are trying to press the device's back button. if you are calling this method on some view click could add that code also?

Comment: I am only touching the back button on the activity. This is where I expect the onBackPressed() to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or commenting out this line :

```
super.onBackPressed()
```

also instead of:

```
println("onBackPressed CALLED")
```

try instead:

```
import android.util.Log
...
Log.v("onBackPressed","onBackPressed CALLED")
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions, with no result at all.

Comment: What happens when you press the back button ? Does the app close ?

Comment: No the app does not close, but the onBackPressed() function is not called as I expect it should.

Comment: I made another post to cleanly reformulate the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075124/why-onbackpressed-is-not-fired-when-touching-back-button-android

Comment: well, I have no clue what the problem might be, but is there any chance that you have some accessibility feature activated or you somehow remapped the back button through develeopper options?

Comment: I don't think do; or at least not that I know of.