# Why onBackPressed() is not fired when touching Back-Button / Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In order to reproduce my issue I made a tiny project. It has two activities.

Here is the *MainActivity.kt* file:

```
package me.soft.trybackbtnaction

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }


    fun fireSubActivity(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, SubActivity::class.java).apply {}
        startActivity(intent)
    } /* End of fireSubActivity */
}
```

Here is the *SubActivity.kt* file:

```
package me.soft.trybackbtnaction

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class SubActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub)
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        println("onBackPressed CALLED")
    }
}
```

And this is the *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TryBackBtnAction"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".SubActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And to be complete below are the activities XML files.

*activity_main.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="fireSubActivity"
        android:text="Fire Sub-Activity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*activity_sub.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Sub-Activity"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When running the app and tapping the back arrow from the sub-activity I expect the *onBackPressed()* function to be called, but that does not happen.

Comment: did you check other Activity lifecycle methods? are they called?

Comment: Have you tried using the new `onBackPressedDispatcher`?

Comment: @Faisal ur Rehman. onCreate, onResume, onStop, onDestroy are all called.
Only onBackPressed for some unknown reason is not called.

Comment: @DarShan. No I didn't try that. Is it something that I need to do to make it work ?

Comment: Its a new api, however your `onBackPressed` should've worked, but you can try the newer one as well.

Comment: I would like to know why `onBackPressed` did not work. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @DarShan. By the way I am trying to find out how to use onBackPressedDispatcher. I am not able to find any good tutorial. Is onBackPressedDispatcher supposed to be used with fragments or not? In my current app I am not using fragments.

Comment: I've added an example via Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new `onBackPressedDispatcher` on the newer versions of the `AppCompatActivity` which work for both Fragment & Activities.

Example:

1. Activity

```kotlin
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // handle back press here.
    }
})
```

2. Fragment

```kotlin
val dispatcher = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher
dispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // handle back press in fragments.
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I can use it as a base to try out something.
Before thinking about how to properly use this onBackPressedDispatcher/onBackPressed thing; I already noticed some missunderstanding on my part. When I talk about the back button I am referring to the button made available inside the app when adding android:parentActivityName="..." to the activity inside AndroidManifst.xml. But the back button firing onBackPressed is not the same "back button". It is the "hardware button" displayed at the botton of the phone independently of the app.

Comment: So I need to say that I want to know wich function fires up when the app back button is touched.

Comment: do you mean the ‘back arrow’ button on the left side of the toolbar?

Comment: See my new post to see what I mean:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231342/how-to-handle-the-application-back-button-in-an-android-app